# Como alterar background-color padrão do .active Bootstrap 4

Tags: front-end, bootstrap-4

Boas colegas. Estou com um pequeno problema que ainda não consegui resolver, a questão é a seguinte: Pretendo trocar a cor de um elemento que é dropdown-item quando este está activo, ou seja quando está na pagina corrente. Deixarei algumas imagens e o código html para ajudar na compreensão.Passei por alguns post, mas nao deu efeito....

[image: Imagem do elemento no website]

código fonte

```html
<header>
....
<nav>
....
<div class="dropdown">
                                    <a
                                        href="/_pages/gallery.html" class="nav-link
                                        font-weight-bolder dropdown-toggle nav-item
                                        mr-3" role="button" id="dropdownmenu"
                                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                                        aria-expanded="false">Galeria</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu mt-2"
                                        aria-labelledby="dropdownmenu">
                                        <a href="/_pages/gallery-pictures.html" class="dropdown-item">Fotografias</a>
                                        <a href="/_pages/gallery-videos.html" class="dropdown-item">Videos</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
</nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisa mudar o estilo da classe `dropdown`. Aninhado a ela, a classe do botão ativo é `.dropdown-item .active`

O css fica assim:

```
.dropdown-item.active,
.dropdown-item:active {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff
}
```

Veja mais na documentação do bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/dropdowns/

Comment: Infelizmente não resultou já tinha feito algo parecido, mas não tinha dado resultado